# Questrade: Tax Free Trading Account. Why don't other brokers in Canada have these?

Tags: canada, investing, stocks, trading, tfsa

I noticed Questrade has a [Tax Free Trading Account](http://www.questrade.com/trading/tax_free_faq.aspx).

Is this too good to be true? Why do other brokers not have a "Tax Free Trading Account" where your gains are not taxed and where you can contribute up to $5000 per year?

Comment: Note, the fourth question on the page states: `How much can I contribute to the TFSA per year?`  That, combined with the cute "correction" of `savings` -> `trading` gives it away as pure marketing.  Pretty slick, eh?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the majority of Canadian banks/brokerages *do* have these.  American or foreign companies might not.

What they're offering is really just a [Tax Free Savings Account](http://www.tfsa.gc.ca/) with fairly low fees and a few bells and whistles.  TD Waterhouse also offers a [TFSA as part of its Discount Brokerage service](http://www.tdwaterhouse.ca/discountbrokerage/tfsa/) (i.e. direct trading).  There's actually a [long list of TFSA Brokerage Accounts here](http://dan.matan.ca/Tax-Free-Savings-Account-TFSA-Brokers-Stocks-Bonds-ETFs).

The only real difference I see is that Questrade has made up their own acronym to represent the same set of services and features that are offered by almost every other Canadian brokerage firm.  In other words, it's marketing.

Comment: +1.  Marketing, indeed.  However, I do wish the Canadian government had named these accounts something other than "Savings" accounts.  Perhaps "Tax Free **Investment** Account". Too many unenlightened head to their bank to open a cash savings TFSA, missing out on the real action in avoiding tax on capital gains & dividends.

Comment: @Chris: I'm not old enough to actually *remember* this, but if my history is correct, RSPs (Retirement *Savings* Plans) were originally just savings accounts, where you might occasionally be able to buy bonds or funds, and you couldn't actually withdraw money. It was only recently that the "Self-Directed RSP" concept came about, and even now there's no clear difference in naming between a direct-trading SDRSP and the old-fashioned, call-us-and-we'll-make-the-trade-whenever-we-feel-like-it kind.  I too lament the misleading names, but not everybody invests either. :)

Comment: @Chris: the worst part about that is that people actually *treat* it like a savings account, and make frequent deposits and withdrawals during the year. [This thread](http://forums.redflagdeals.com/my-tfsa-balance-200-cra-wants-me-pay-interest-5700-wtf-899497/) highlights the implications of that behaviour.